# JS to add class to multiple elements that share class "project name" when hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I'm building a grid of portfolio items. I'd like to link the hover effect for items if they're from the same project.

Basically: on hover, if another element shares this class, trigger hover effect for that element also by adding class "faux-hover".

```
<div class="project red faux-hover"> HOVERED </div>
<div class="project blue">  </div>
<div class="project green">  </div>
<div class="project red faux-hover">  </div>
<div class="project red faux-hover">  </div>
<div class="project blue">  </div>
<div class="project green">  </div>
<div class="project blue">  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your hover effect in css and then add this function

```js
function trigger(){
  $('.project.red').hover(function (){$('.project.red').addClass('faux-hover')
},function (){$('.project.red').removeClass('faux-hover')})
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  What would be the best way to generalize it? Basically, instead of targeting "red", referencing "item currently being hovered". I think this would be best instead of adding a function for every project. There are many :)